# Django test fixtures: How to cope with test data involving time?

Tags: django, testing, dynamic-data, fixtures

Currently I am doing TDD on a reusable Django app. One test should make sure that my view only returns articles that have a publish-date that is in the past. I am quite new to testing in Django. So far I have learned how to use `.json` files as fixtures for my test classes.

However for this test I do not want to insert publish dates that are 1000 years in the future. After all another species might discover our ancient internet, check out my source and wonder why my test fails :) What other approaches are there to solve this problem? Static `.json` files seem to be a bit hard to maintain as well as the application grows... mocking the `datetime.datetime.now()` method in my tests feels tedious as well.

There must be an easy way to produce the `.json` fixture on the fly before  the test runs and always have 2 days from now as the publish-date for some of my entries...

Answer (score 1):

You could try subclassing the datetime functions (see ["Using Mock objects in Django for testing the current date"](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/aug/14/using-mock-objects-django-and-python-testing/)).

Answer (score 1):

Mocking datetime was my first thought as well but as LaundroMat pointet out in his blog post himself, this is rather hacky and bad.

I came up with another solution:

I just gave up on .json fixtures. I don't even know why Django encourages to use them. They look ugly and they are impossible to maintain.

Instead I added a module test_data.py to my fixtures folder. That module imports my models and defines some nice methods that create test-data for me. In my tests.py I dropped the fixtures = ['some_json_file'] line and added a setUp() method instead. This method executes my 'dynamic fixtures' from my test_data.py module.

This is so simple and obvious that I wonder if there is anything wrong with this approach. If no one comments on this solution, I will mark is as accepted in a couple of weeks or so...

Comment: Hmm maybe one thing that is wrong with this approach is, that by using the models itself to create test data, I am using the things I want to test itself in order to produce test data. That means, if I override the save() method, producing my test data might already introduce buggy data... but still in most cases this should be caught by sane asserts I do in my tests so right now I don't think this is a super big issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [django dynamic fixture](https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture), it will fill date/time properties automatically for you.

Comment: automatic is fine, but how do i get it to fill in eg. dates "in the future" and "in the past" if i have to test different outcomes for both cases?

Answer (score 0):

### Creating test data

Indeed it is far more flexible to create your test data with Python.
There are several packages that support such things, for instance

- [model-backery](https://pypi.org/project/model-bakery/)
- [django-dynamic-fixture](https://pypi.org/project/django-dynamic-fixture/)

These two use fairly different approaches. Have a look and pick the one you like more.
You can also write data generation functions *from scratch*. If you partition your logic carefully, this is not overly cumbersome.

### Handling time

For tests involving time, the right approach is indeed mocking -- but don't do it yourself, use a nice library. See for instance

- [freezegun](https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/)

There is even a [pytest plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-freezegun/) for it.